# I am fully updated on Windows 8.1 Pro, and I can't see the Get Windows 10 Icon

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10

My copy of windows is activated with a legitimate license. I have updated everything and when I go to Windows Update it says everything is updated too. But I can't see the Get Windows 10 icon on the taskbar. Recently, I have upgraded to 64-bit. Before I upgraded I could see the icon, and after I updated I couldn't. I updated on the 28th of July. Is this because of my upgrade to 64-bit? Or is it because it takes a while to appear after reformatting my computer? Again, everything is updated.

Comment: It's possible that Windows Update server delay the update. Anyway it doesn't matter, you can just grab the latest ISO [rightaway](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and start upgrading, it will automatically activate as long as you upgrade from 7/8, regardless if you've reserved Windows 10 on that PC

Answer (score 4):

Download the [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install?ocid=ms_wol_win10) and follow the steps under *Run the tool* on that page. You should have an **Upgrade this PC now** button.

---

A quick amendment to @Fazer87's method #1, which will not work for you but may benefit others:

1. Make sure you have reserved your free copy of Windows 10.
2. Run Windows Update and make sure you are set to receive updates automatically.
3. Navigate to `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download` folder and delete everything in this folder.
4. Now run Command Prompt utility in Administrator mode. Simply search for `cmd` from Start Menu/Screen, right-click, and then click on **Run as administrator**.
5. Type this command and *do not* press enter: `wuauclt.exe /updatenow`
6. Open Windows Update and press `Check for Updates`.
7. While this is running press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in your Command Prompt window.
8. Allow the update to download and install.

Source: http://venturebeat.com/2015/07/28/how-to-force-windows-to-start-downloading-the-windows-10-update-files/

Comment: Well, *how* to execute Step 1...?

Comment: @Arjan, I've now edited my main post.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here:

1) Force windows update to get the Upgrade:

- Step 1: Make sure you have reserved your free copy of Windows 10.
- Step 2: Run Windows Update, and make sure you are set to receive updates automatically.
- Step 3: Navigate to C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download folder and delete everything in this folder.
- Step 4: Now run Command Prompt utility in Administrator mode. Simply search for ‘cmd’ from Start Menu/Screen, right click, and then click on run as administrator.
- Step 5: Type this command and press enter: *wuauclt.exe /updatenow*.
- Step 6: Allow the update to download and install

---

2) Download the ISO and install.  You can get the by downloading the media creator tool from:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

And using the ISO conversion option.  Alternatively, you can use the tool to create install media directly.

---

3) Try manually opening the "Get Windows" (GWX.exe) app from:

- C:\Windows\System32\GWX

OR

- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\GWX (in 64-bit systems only)

If you are unable to run the windows 10 reservation app, try running the following as an administrator (copy to notepad, save as batch file):

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\UpgradeExperienceIndicators" /v UpgEx | findstr UpgEx

if "%errorlevel%" == "0" GOTO RunGWX

reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Appraiser" /v UtcOnetimeSend /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

schtasks /run /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser"

:CompatCheckRunning

schtasks /query /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser"

schtasks /query /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser" | findstr Ready

if NOT "%errorlevel%" == "0" ping localhost >nul &goto :CompatCheckRunning

:RunGWX

schtasks /run /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Setup\gwx\refreshgwxconfig"
```

Comment: There is no **.iso** file, only a link to download _media creation tool_ ?

Comment: @RogUE - that tool includes a "Optional conversion to ISO file format" option.. its literally the last line before the download link.  Will update to remove ambiguity

Comment: It is an online installer, isn't it?

Comment: Seems like Step 1 of option 1 is impossible for the question asker...